# pick image form gallery not display after close application

Tags: android

Set image in `com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView` from gallery  image display after close android app image not showing in android studio

```
imgbtnSetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 100);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            try {


                Uri uriImage = data.getData();
                  circuler_imgView.setImageURI(uriImage);

}
```

Comment: Yes. If you close your app it cannot show images indeed. And certainly not in Android Studio.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html